# What's this drum symbol (X with line in the middle without tail)

Tags: notation, drums

Can someone please help me identify this drum symbol?

[image: Drum Symbol]

It's from the second bar here:

[image]

Comment: Could you maybe provide a complete example where it is used exactly that way?

Comment: Hi Matthias, I can post the full purcussion line where this occurs, e.g.: 4 bar stave.

Comment: Hmm, I looked for references but I didn't find the particular symbol anywhere. Perhaps it is just a crash cymbal, but it's strange because you would expect a normal x like you see it before. Is this from a song or an excercise. Where did you get it?

Comment: It comes directly from the 'Futurama Theme' which I purchased from sheet music plus - http://www.sheetmusicplus.com/title/futurama-theme-digital-sheet-music/20067830. It contains an audio representation of the sheet music, so you should be able to hear the questioned cymbal at the end.

Answer (score 4):

I have never seen something like this before and couldn't find anything either, so my guess would be that it's a crash cymbal that lasts a whole note (semibreve). I'm guessing it's shaped like that to resemble the whole note.

Comment: I'd be inclined to agree you, with one note: I think the note is just an empty X without stem.  The line is the ledger line. You can see the note head here: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/27453/different-note-head-uses-in-musescore

Answer (score 0):

Some of the references say that its a Ride cymbal which is similar to the hi-hats which is played on the imaginary line above the measure. Actually the 'x' sits on the line and that is the reason it looks like a star.

Comment: Hi Shwetha, I'm trying to work out how long the length of the cymbal is. I presume it is the same length as a piano sembibreve, but I'm not sure.